# Axios.all in NodeJS failing with 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, axios

I hope you can help me because it is HOURS of trying to get this problem resolved. I've googled so much and tried all of the solutions I found, but I keep getting the same error. 
I am trying to make an axis get a request to an API that is paginated for 1 result per page, loop through all of the results, and resolve the promises with the promise array. 
I have verified that without the loop, just getting 1 request, everything works. I have successful writing to MongoDB using MongoDB driver and its fine. Once I bring the loop in I cannot get the promises to resolve. I was able to console.log that the promise array does, indeed, have x number of pending promises in them.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb')
const axios = require('axios');
const url = 'https://catfact.ninja/fact'

let db = null;
let client = null;

//this one works great
const getMetaData = function () {  
    let data = axios.get(url+"s")
    .then(response => {
        return response.data
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
   return data;
}
//this one will not resolve
const dataArray =  async function (total) {
    let baseUrl = url+"s/facts?page="
    let res =[];    
    let promises = [];
    for (let page = 1; page <= total; page++){
        promises.push(axios.get(baseUrl+page))
    }
    axios.all(promises).then(result => console.log(result))
   //originally i wanted to map the result to an array of json
  //objects, but if i could even get a console.log it would be
 //a win. spread operator not working, Promise.all not working
 //i must have tried 12 different stackoverflow responses from
//other questions. until i can resolve the promises I can't do anything.


    }








exports.connect = async function(url, done) {
    if (db) return done();

   // let data = await getMetaData()
   // let total = data['total']
    let arr = dataArray(5);


    //console.log("arr is "+arr)
    MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err, client){
        if (err) return done(err);
        client = client;
        db = client.db('morefun');    
        /*
        db.collection('catfacts').insertMany(dataArray, function(err, res){
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
        })*/
        done();


    });


}

exports.get = function() {
    return db;
}

//make sure this is correct
exports.close = function(done) {
    if (db) {
        client.close(function(err, result) {
            db = null;
            mode = null;
            done(err);
        });
    }
}
```

I need an array of JSON objects for the insertMany function to work. please someone help me. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *for* loop, you are creating a URL like this: `https://catfact.ninja/facts/facts?page=1` – this is incorrect, the correct URL should be `https://catfact.ninja/facts?page=1` (with *facts* only once).

Also, the keyword `async` is not needed here, and you should return the result of `axios.all`.

A correct version of your code:

```
const dataArray = function (total) {
  let baseUrl = url+"s?page="
  let res =[];    
  let promises = [];
  for (let page = 1; page <= total; page++){
    promises.push(axios.get(baseUrl+page))
  }
  return axios.all(promises).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  });
}
```

You can then get your data like this:

```
let arr = await dataArray(5);
```

**Getting the actual data the way you want it**

From your comments, I see that what you really want is to post-process the data obtained from the API to ultimately get one array that contains only the cat data.

You can do this by “massaging” the data with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), like this:

```
return axios
    .all(promises)
    .then(result => result.map(({ data }) => data.data).reduce((curr, acc) => acc.concat(curr), []));
```

Note: I've left out the console.log statement here for brevity.

- The actual data is nested as property 'data' in an object within an object as property 'data', so the *map* call retrieves that
- We get an array of arrays, each with an object with cat data; the *reduce* call flattens this to a simple array of cat data

We get a result that looks like this, which is hopefully what you want :

```
[
    {
        "fact": "Cats see six times better in the dark and at night than humans.",
        "length": 63
    },
    {
        "fact": "The ability of a cat to find its way home is called “psi-traveling.” Experts think cats either use the angle of the sunlight to find their way or that cats have magnetized cells in their brains that act as compasses.",
        "length": 220
    },
    {
        "fact": "Cat's urine glows under a black light.",
        "length": 38
    },
    {
        "fact": "There are more than 500 million domestic cats in the world, with approximately 40 recognized breeds.",
        "length": 100
    },
    {
        "fact": "A tomcat (male cat) can begin mating when he is between 7 and 10 months old.",
        "length": 76
    }
]
```

Comment: thank you so much.... this is what happens after 15 hours of coding. I really need to go to bed... After updating with your code I can get the promises resolved, but the data includes the header which i don't want, and the data I do want is nested in a data: [array]  do you know how to pull out the array and leave off the header? with a single get request I just used response.data but its not working with the promise.all syntax. it come back undefined... thank you!!

Comment: added the answer, you didn't specify how exactly want your data to look. If this is not precisely what you need, hopefully it will point you in the right direction

Comment: You are AMAZING Patrick. not only do you know exactly what you are doing, you know how to read the minds of walking-dead coders who can't articulate anymore! Thank you SO much. you gave me exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 0):

No sure if it's the answer but I know I've ran into issues when not using the syntax axios wants exactly for an axios all.

`axios.all([fetch1request(), fetch2request()]).then(axios.spread((fetch1, fetch2 ) => * whatever logic you need. But at this point the requests are complete* })`

Comment: Thanks for helping Jacob. This is very helpful to see how axios actually recommends use .all